# How to publish python code as web api on iis

Tags: python, iis, publishing, flask-restful

I am new to Python deployment. I have a Python Web API made in Flask. Want guidance on how to publish the python code as web API so that Dot Net program can consume it and take benefit of Python / ML.

Apologies for such generic question, but any help or approach or documentations on the same would be grateful.

Thanks In Advance!!!..

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, if you want to deploy python application to the IIS.  I suggest you could follow below steps:

1.Install [Python](https://www.python.org/) on your server.

2.Install [wfastcgi](https://pypi.org/project/wfastcgi/) on your server.

3.Install the IIS(contol panel->Programs->Programs and Features->Turn Windows Features on or Off) with the CGI

[image]

4.Create a new IIS web app for the paython project folder.

[image]

5.Modify the handler mapping to add python handler. Notice: Modify the path based on your python and wfastcgi path

[image]

6. Run your application

More details, you could refer to below article:

https://www.storehubs.com/Blog/deploy-python-flask-application-iis/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019

Comment: link of article is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

One of the links provided was broken. I found one that I believe is the same as the broken link from the previous answer. It did help me.
[Deploy a Python Flask Application in IIS Server and run on machine IP address](https://medium.com/@dpralay07/deploy-a-python-flask-application-in-iis-server-and-run-on-machine-ip-address-ddb81df8edf3)

Comment: you should use comments or suggest an edit instead of posting this as an answer post

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I just attempted to deploy **Python flask application** on IIS.

However, fastCGI method does not apply to my case.

Instead, I highly recommended **HttpPlatformHandler** method to deploy your python application.

It is way easier than setting up complicated configurations in fastCGI module.

Besides, Microsoft also highlighted that fastCGI approach is not recommended to deploy Python flask application due to **its unavailability of maintaining the module in LR**.

Hence, there is another approach I found yesterday, which surprisingly resolved my problem of deploying the app **less than half an hour**.

Helpful link: https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

To conclude the usefulness of this link, you simply need to create a single file of **web.config**, containing **the correct process path**, which is the **path of python execution file** as well as the main application you would like to execute.

Create **web.config** file in your main directory, and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        
        <httpPlatform startupTimeLimit="10" startupRetryCount="10" stdoutLogEnabled="true" processPath="Input the path of your python execution file" arguments="-m flask run --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%">
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="foo" value="bar"/>
                
            </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Activate the web browsing, then give a try whether this solution meets your needs!