# deploy Masonite framework on windows IIS

Tags: python-3.x, windows, web-deployment, iis-8, masonite

I have struggled to deploy Python Masonite build web app on windows IIS. Does anyone here has done that before. Do you might to share the guides online for me to reference?

I tried to follow Djagon and Flask framework deployment approach but it could not work.

Comment: What have you tried, and did you receive any errors when you tried it?

Comment: As long as you can host your web app on a Python based application server (such as waitress) it is rather easy to then host such on IIS via HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ Note that everything can be verified at command line first.

Comment: Did you refer to the official documentation: [Configure Python web apps for IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2022). And modify the handler mapping to add python handler or related operations. Simple refer to this [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56883433/how-to-publish-python-code-as-web-api-on-iis).